# Uniform convergence through Supremum

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, supremum-and-infimum

I came up with a solution to a simple problem that I was working on but it seemed too simplistic so I doubt that my solution is correct which is why I want some help. $f_n(x)$ is a sequence of complex valued functions on set $X$ and $f(x) $ is another complex function on the same set.

Show that $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ uniformly for $n \rightarrow \infty$ if: $$ \sup_{x\in X}|f_n(x)-f(x)| \rightarrow 0. $$
My attempt:
$$ \inf_{x \in X}|f_n(x)-f(x)|≤ |f_n(x)-f(x)| ≤ \sup_{x \in X} |f_n(x)-f(x)|$$
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \inf_{x \in X}|f_n(x)-f(x)|≤\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f_n(x)-f(x)|≤  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{x \in X}|f_n(x)-f(x)| $$
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |f_n(x)-f(x)| ≤\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{x \in X}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0 ≤ \epsilon.$$
Initially I wanted to make an argument using the squeeze theorem for limits but I didn't know how to proceed with the limit of infimum so this was what I had. I don't think its entirely wrong but I'm sure I'm missing something here.

Comment: What is your definition of uniform convergence?

Comment: Usually, for sequences $(f_n)$ and function $f$ defined in a set $X$ with values in a metric space, say $\mathbb{R}$ for simplicity, it is said the $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $n_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in S$whenever $n\geq n_\varepsilon$ (to be continue)

Comment: (continue) if you look at the definition above long enough, you realize that that the whole thin is equivalent to: for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is $n_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sup_{x\in S}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq\varepsilon$ whenever $n\geq n_\varepsilon$. That is equivalent to saying that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{x\in S}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$